# Synonym for "turn to"

Tags: synonyms

What is a good synonym for the phrase *turn to* used to mean the firm intent to do an action after having completed a previous action such as in these examples?

> He completed the reports then **turned to** the accounts.
>
> We've discussed the vacation - now let's **turn to** the salaries.

Comment: I do not understand the significance of *"the firm intent"* in the question. There is no such implication in either *"turn to"* or any of the suggested alternatives - it's only indicated by *"let's"* in the second example.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest: ***move on to***, *proceed to*, *go on to*, or the very common ***switch to***.

> He completed the reports then moved on to the accounts

Answer (score 2):

1. He completed the reports then *took up* the accounts.
   We've discussed the vacation - now let's *take up* the salaries.
2. He completed the reports then *started on / got to* the accounts.
   We've discussed the vacation - now let's *start on / get to* the salaries.
3. He completed the reports then *attended to* the accounts.
   We've discussed the vacation - now let's *attend to* the salaries.

Comment: +1 for 'Attended to'. Also 'turned his attention to'.

Answer (score 1):

You might *[tackle](http://thesaurus.com/browse/tackle)* the next activity, if you mean to go at a difficult task with gusto:

> He completed the reports, then *tackled* the accounts.
>   We've discussed the vacation—now let's *tackle* the salaries.

You might also *[address](http://thesaurus.com/browse/address)* or *focus on* the next thing. Or, to more strongly show that you've moved from one task and started another, you could *set about* discussing the salaries or *apply yourself* to reconciling the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple "We've discussed X and now let's discuss Y"?